# Is there a way to make Eclipse (with pydev) insert an empty docstring at the start of every class or def statement?

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I'm trying to get in the habit of writing docstrings, and one way I think I could force myself to do that would be by automatically having Eclipse insert an empty docstring when I type a class or a def statement. It's only 8 key presses but it seems handy to me.
Would creating my own Eclipse plugin be the best method?
Just for reference, I'd like it to look something like this (yes I know the function is silly, it's just a demo):

```
def timeInit():
    '''

    '''
    return ti.time()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PyDev doesn't do that automatically, but you can do `Ctrl+1` in the `def` line and select the option for it to generate the docstring for you (it'll include all params in the docstring).

Another option is creating a template (in `preferences > pydev > editor > templates`) which automatically comes with the docstring and then use it to create the method (or you can edit the existing `def` template.

Comment: This has gotten me 90% of the way there (specifically `ctrl+1`). I am hoping you or someone else could clarify one additional question I have though: I have edited the template in the Pydev preferences but when I use `ctrl+1` on a undefined function call, the generated function just reads as
`testfunc(): 
    pass`

Comment: EDIT: nevermind, I understand templates now! (couldn't edit last comment anymore)
Man I have trouble hitting enter on here too much...